# connecting smart contract in solidity front end with ropsten test net

Tags: solidity

Index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Coursetro Instructor</h1>

        <h2 id="instructor"></h2>

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text">

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Age</label>
        <input id="age" type="text">

        <button id="button">Update Instructor</button>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        var Web3  = require('web3');
        const abiDecoder = require('abi-decoder');
        let web3 = new Web3();

        //Set http provider (geth running ip&port)
        web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://192.168.1.126:8545'));
        }
        //web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_fname","type":"string"},{"name":"_age","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setInstructor","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"age","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getInstructor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fname","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);

        var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x944d85D9010517c35b16163eA12E0d0d59A57018');
        console.log(Coursetro);

        Coursetro.getInstructor(function(error, result){
            if(!error)
                {
                    $("#instructor").html(result[0]+' ('+result[1]+' years old)');
                    console.log(result);
                }
            else
                console.error(error);
        });

        $("#button").click(function() {
            Coursetro.setInstructor($("#name").val(), $("#age").val());
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Main.css file :

```
body {
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    padding: 2em;
    font-family: 'Raleway','Source Sans Pro', 'Arial';
}
.container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
label {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
input {
    padding:10px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
button {
    margin: 2em 0;
    padding: 1em 4em;
    display:block;
}

#instructor {
    padding:1em;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
#loader {
    width: 100px;
    display:none;
}
```

Smart contract in remix :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract Coursetro{
    string public fname;
    uint public age;

       function setInstructor(string _fname,uint _age) public{ //demo is constructor function
        fname = _fname;
        age = _age;
                    }
    function getInstructor() public constant returns(string,uint){
        return(fname,age);
    }
}
```

Steps which I have followed:

- I have run ropsten testnet and using meta mask I have run my smart contract in remix.
- Then I have taken ABI and address from remix and  put in javascript code.
- Here I am getting the error.

Comment: Hi there. What error are you getting? Where are you seeing it? (Please can you fix the formatting in your question? It will help others to understand your problem better.)

Comment: Thanx..i have solved it myself :)

Comment: That's great :-) Could you add an answer to your question describing what you did? That way it will help other people who also have the problem. (You can then also accept your own answer, meaning this question won't just sit open until the end of time.)